# How to get value from textbox in Jquery modal box

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I m using a user control on my page, I am opening this user control in a jquery modal popup window.
I want to perform some action on button click using jquery but when I try to check the value of my textbox I m getting blank value

Here is the code I am using

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I am trying to alert the value

```
alert($('#ContentPlaceHolder1_User_txtName').val());

<input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_User_txtName" type="text" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$User$txtName">
```

Jquery used 1.5

I have tried using

```
    $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>")
    $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_User_txtName').val(); 
    $("#txtName").text();
    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_User_txtName").text();
```

Every time I am getting "" value
Please tell me where I m making mistake

> (function($) {
>       $.modal = function(config) {

```
    var defaults, options, modal, header, content, footer, close, overlay, width, centerOffset;

    defaults = {            
        title: ''
        , byline: ''

        , ajax: ''
        , div: ''   

        , slide: false  
        , slideEl: '.slide' 

        , btnClass: 'btn small secondary'

        , overlay: true
        , overlayClose: true

        , beforeOpen: function () {}
        , afterOpen: function () {}

        , debug: false
    };

    options = $.extend(defaults, config);       

    $.modal.forceClose ();

    modal = $('<div>', { 'id' : 'modal' });     
    header = $('<div>', { 'id' : 'modal_header' });     
    content = $('<div>', { 'id' : 'modal_content' });           
    overlay = $('<div>', { 'id' : 'modal_overlay'   });     
    close = $('<div>', { 'id' : 'modal_close' , 'html': 'x' });

    header.appendTo (modal);
    content.appendTo (modal);
    close.appendTo (modal);

    options.beforeOpen (modal);

    modal.appendTo ('body').hide ().fadeIn (500);

    if (options.overlay) {
        overlay.appendTo ('body');
    }

    if (options.overlayClose) {
        overlay.bind ('click', function (e) { $.modal.close (); });
    }

    close.bind ('click', function (e) { $.modal.close (); });       

    (options.title !== '') ? header.append ('<h3>' + options.title + '</h3>') : '';             
    (options.byline !== '') ? header.append ('<div class="byline">' + options.byline + '</div>') : '';  

    if (options.ajax !== '') {
        content.html ('<div id="modal_loader"><img src="../images/mba/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>');
        $.modal.reposition ();
        $.get (options.ajax, function (response) {
            content.html (response);
            handleContent ();
        });
    }                       

    if (options.div !== '') {
        content.html ($(options.div).html());
        handleContent ();
    }   

    function handleContent () {
        $.modal.reposition ();      
        if (options.slide) { handleSlides (); }     

        setTimeout (function () {   
            options.afterOpen (modal);
        }, 1000);
    }   

    function handleSlides () {
        var slides = modal.find (options.slideEl);              
        slides.hide ().eq (0).show ().addClass ('current_slide');           
        var footer = $('<div>', { id: 'modal_footer' }).appendTo (modal);           
        var prev = $('<button>', { id: 'prev', html: '<u>P</u>revious' }).addClass (options.btnClass).appendTo (footer);
        var display = $('<span>', { id: 'display' }).appendTo (footer);
        var next = $('<button>', { id: 'next', html: '<u>N</u>ext' }).addClass (options.btnClass).appendTo (footer);            
        display.html ('<span class="current_page">1</span> of ' + slides.length);
        prev.attr ('disabled', 'disabled'); 

        $(document).bind ('keyup.modal', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 78 || e.keyCode == 39) { navigateSlides ('forward', slides); }
            if (e.keyCode == 80 || e.keyCode == 37) { navigateSlides ('backward', slides); }
        });

        footer.find ('button').bind ('click', function (e) {
            var direction = ($(this).is ('#next')) ? 'forward' : 'backward';
            navigateSlides (direction, slides);
        });

    }

    function navigateSlides (direction, slides) {
        var currentSlide, nextSlide, next, prev;
        next = $('#next');
        prev = $('#prev');
        currentSlide = content.find ('.current_slide');                 
        nextSlide = (direction == 'forward') ? currentSlide.next (options.slideEl) : currentSlide.prev (options.slideEl);           

        if (nextSlide.length > 0) {
            nextSlide.addClass ('current_slide').show ().siblings (options.slideEl).hide ().removeClass ('current_slide');
            $('#display .current_page').text (nextSlide.index () + 1);

            (nextSlide.index () === 0) ? prev.attr ('disabled', 'disabled') : prev.removeAttr ('disabled');
            (nextSlide.index () === slides.length - 1) ? next.attr ('disabled', 'disabled') : next.removeAttr ('disabled');     

            var contentWidth = nextSlide.outerWidth ();                 
            content.width (contentWidth + 30);
            //$.modal.reposition ();    
        }                           
    }

    $(document).bind ('keyup.modal', function (e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { $.modal.close (); }          
    });     

};

$.modal.reposition = function () {
    var width = $('#modal').outerWidth ();      
    var centerOffset = width / 2;   
    var pageScroll = getPageScroll ();  
    $('#modal').css ({ 'left': '50%', 'top': pageScroll[1] + 100, 'margin-left': '-' + centerOffset + 'px' });
};

$.modal.close = function () {
    $('#modal').fadeOut ('medium', function () { $(this).remove (); });
    $('#modal_overlay').fadeOut ('medium', function () { $(this).remove (); });
    $(document).unbind ('keyup.modal');
};

$.modal.forceClose = function () {
    $('#modal').remove ();
    $('#modal_overlay').remove ();
    $(document).unbind ('keyup.modal');
};

$.modal.setTitle = function (title) {
    var h3 = $('#modal_header').find ('h3');        
    if (h3.length > 0) {
        h3.html (title);
    } else {
        $('<h3>', { html: title }).prependTo ('#modal_header'); 
    }
};

$.modal.setByline = function (text) {
    var el = $('#modal_header').find ('.byline');       
    if (el.length > 0) {
        el.html (text);
    } else {
        $('<div>', { 'class': 'byline', html: text }).appendTo ('#modal_header');   
    }
};

// getPageScroll() by quirksmode.com
    function getPageScroll() {
        var xScroll, yScroll;
        if (self.pageYOffset) {
          yScroll = self.pageYOffset;
          xScroll = self.pageXOffset;
        } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {     // Explorer 6 Strict
          yScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          xScroll = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        } else if (document.body) {// all other Explorers
          yScroll = document.body.scrollTop;
          xScroll = document.body.scrollLeft;
        }
        return new Array(xScroll,yScroll);
      }
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").val()); 
});
```

Comment: when I try this code to run on IE console it gives me blank value $("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").val()

Comment: Try this $("input[id$=txtName]").val();

Answer (score 0):

You look like you have it to me:

```
$(function() {
  alert($("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").val());
}
```

Have you put it in the document.ready block? As it could be firing before the page has loaded.

Either as above (shorthand) or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // Do stuff once the DOM is ready
 });
```

Appended with the modal:

```
    $(function () {
        alert($('#<%= txtName.ClientID %>').val());
        $.modal({ title: $('#<%= txtName.ClientID %>').val() });
    });
```

Both the alert and the modal is working for me (with the new title as the text box value).
I have a "text" attribute populated in the `TextBox` so it'll work onload.

If I put the code outside of a `$(document).ready(function() {` block then it'll not work. However, inside I'm getting all the expected results. First an alert, then the modal fading in with the revised title.

When you load the page and check your source, the javascript has the correct textbox ID written to it?

Comment: when I try this code to run on IE console it gives me blank value
$("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").val()

Comment: @Aman I've just ran it myself and it works fine... You've correctly referenced the jQuery file? `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` for a CDN version.

Comment: I have tried it again but this is not working
I am sending you modal jquery hope that can help

Comment: I've just added some more details with the modal code you've posted. Let me know.

Comment: Hi
I have tried to work on the code The modal work fine for me as well
Now place a textbox and a button inside it, then try to get the value of textbox on button click. I have checked this with all the browser but it is not working for me. please let me know if u have any query